# Golang: After Mac update 13.4.1 (c), "go test" fails using terminal or in debug mode

Tags: macos, go

After Mac update 13.4.1 (c) with intel processor, "go test" fails using the terminal or in debug mode

```
Build Error: go test -c -o /Users/mananpat/Desktop/go/src/github.com/openconfig/featureprofiles/feature/gribi/ate_tests/cisco/ha/__debug_bin496041978 -gcflags all=-N -l .
# github.com/openconfig/featureprofiles/feature/gribi/ate_tests/cisco/ha.test
/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64/link: running clang failed: exit status 1
ld: warning: -bind_at_load is deprecated on macOS
ld: warning: '/private/var/folders/nv/6_0g9kjn35z8t1kct1rccgyc0000gn/T/go-link-3042092994/go.o' has malformed LC_DYSYMTAB, expected 131 undefined symbols to start at index 681748, found 141 undefined symbols starting at index 114
0  0x10f50de8a  __assert_rtn + 64
1  0x10f4b57a9  ___ZN2ld16LayoutExecutable27writeContentWithoutLinkEditENSt3__14spanIhLm18446744073709551615EEEy_block_invoke + 9913
2  0x7ff8049bf066  _dispatch_client_callout2 + 8
3  0x7ff8049d0e09  _dispatch_apply_invoke + 213
4  0x7ff8049bf033  _dispatch_client_callout + 8
5  0x7ff8049cf0f6  _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 683
6  0x7ff8049cf768  _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 170
7  0x7ff804b5cc0f  _pthread_wqthread + 257
ld: Assertion failed: (addr + content.size() <= sectionEndAddr), function writeContentWithoutLinkEdit_block_invoke, file Layout.cpp, line 5689.
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) (exit status 1)
```

I tried removing Go and moving to the latest version

mike-M-VJMD:go mike$ which go
/usr/local/go/bin/go

mike-M-VJMD:go mike$ go version
go version go1.20.5 darwin/amd64

mike-M-VJMD:go mike$ echo $GOPATH
/Users/mike/Desktop/go

/Users/mike/Desktop/go/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin:/usr/local/go/bin

go env

```
mike-M-VJMD:go mike$ go env
GO111MODULE=""
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/Users/mike/Library/Caches/go-build"
GOENV="/Users/mike/Library/Application Support/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOEXPERIMENT=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOINSECURE=""
GOMODCACHE="/Users/mike/Desktop/go/pkg/mod"
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/mike/Desktop/go"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
GOVCS=""
GOVERSION="go1.20.5"
GCCGO="gccgo"
GOAMD64="v1"
AR="ar"
CC="clang"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD="/dev/null"
GOWORK=""
CGO_CFLAGS="-O2 -g"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-O2 -g"
CGO_FFLAGS="-O2 -g"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-O2 -g"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -arch x86_64 -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/var/folders/nv/6_0g9kjn35z8t1kct1rccgyc0000gn/T/go-build445471948=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -fno-common"
mike-M-VJMD:go mike$
```

go test -v . -testbed x.testbed -binding x.binding" -alsologtostderr true

I am running googles gribi tc https://github.com/openconfig/featureprofiles

Comment: Why did you show use the value of `GOPATH`? Other than for the location where `go get` caches downloaded packages it isn't really relevant for building Go programs any more. Also, you didn't show us the `go test` command you ran or describe the software you are building/testing. Apparently it is using CGO which can be difficult to work with. Finally, the output of `go env` can be important, or at least showing us any env vars likely to affect the build process.

Comment: Update your question with that information. Don't put it in comments to the question. And don't forget to show us the actual `go test` command you are running and describe the software you are building so we have some context.

Comment: I downloaded that package. Your `go test` command is obviously incorrect since it has a stray double-quote. Beyond that you've also left out at least one other important detail such as the CWD. Good luck but I've wasted enough time trying to explain that you have to provide enough detail for someone to reproduce your problem.